# singlenode cluster setup using hadoop-2.4.0 with cygwin

Tags: java, hadoop

I tried singlenode cluster setup in `hadoop-2.4.0` with cygwin, but it is not working, while I am giving the statement like:

```
bin/hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.4.0.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'
```

Then I am getting the error like:

```
bin/hadoop: line 133: /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.5.0_05;/bin/java: No such file or directory
bin/hadoop: line 133: exec: /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.5.0_05;/bin/java: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

Please help me in doing this.

Answer (score 2):

According to Hadoop Wiki, Cygwin is not supported or even required.

*"Do not attempt to run the installation from within Cygwin. Cygwin is neither required nor supported."*

They have instructions on building and running Hadoop on windows, though.

Source: https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hadoop2OnWindows.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set JAVA_HOME in hadoop-env.sh file.